# Problema con .nextLine()

Tags: java, netbeans

No me toma el `nextLine()`, No me deja llenarlo, este es el código:

```
System.out.println("INGRESE NOMBRE: ");  
String nombre = entrada.nextLine();
                    
                   
System.out.println("INGRESE GENERO:");
String genero = entrada.next();
                        
System.out.println("INGRESE DURACION:");
int duracion = entrada.nextInt();
```

cuando lo corro no me deja escribir el nombre:

```
INGRESE NOMBRE: 
INGRESE GENERO:
(Acá espera a que yo teclee algo)
```

Comment: tu codigo esta bien,que problema tienes??

Comment: Cuando lo ejecuto no me deja añadir el nombre, directamente me dice que ingrese el genero. Si pusiera el scanner del nombre con next() si me deja escribirlo, pero ahí sería solo una palabra, no una cadena

Comment: Primera noticia, una palabra no es una cadena. Tienes algún `entrada.next()` antes de ese `nextLine()` del nombre? Porque `nextLine()` lee todo, pero los demás métodos leen solo una parte de lo introducido, dejando siempre en el búfer un salto de línea. Y ese salto de línea es lo que te está leyendo tu `entrada.nextLine()` seguramente. Cuando uses `next()` pon a continuación un `nextLine()` solo para *"limpiar"* el búfer y verás que funciona bien

Comment: Funcionó, gracias!